# HTML Flair Formatting Frakked-Up by Huge Favicon

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, flair, favicon

[The HTML version of the per-site flair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/1114) (intended for embedding via `<iframe>`) seems to have originally been designed assuming a 16px favicon. However, the size of the actual favicon has since been increased to 32px. The extra vertical space this adds shoves the badges out-of-frame.

Adding a `width="16"` attribute to the element fixes the issue, albeit with some fuzziness.

---

#### My Beautiful Flair, *Ruined!*

[image]

> [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]

#### My Beautiful Flair, *Restored!*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the spirit that this question was asked and this bug raised, it has been fixed.

With you in the next build.

Enjoy one of your precious bits of (improved) flair.